# Can you use a custom DNS server within EC2?

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2

I need to set up a custom DNS server within EC2.  I have one instance that acts as the DNS server, and N other instances that use this DNS server to connect to one another.  Is this posible?  Basically, I need to modify the DHCP settings for the N instances so that they connect to the DNS server.  I can't find any good documentation on modifying the DHCP settings  for an instance.

Note: I did find some documents, but they seem to only apply to Amazon VPC.  Is there any way to do this without using VPC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - no.  You need a VPC.  But once you have the VPC created - you can effectively do whatever you like with it.

Long answer - traditional AWS hosting gets an address directly from Amazon.  This means you've got no control whatsoever of the IP addresses.

New accounts however come with a VPC by default, which means you can install a machine to act as a DNS server.  (And I've done this in the past using Windows Active Directory)